# how to set custom claims in my jwt token while getting token from wso2 token issuer

Tags: curl, jwt, wso2, wso2-api-manager

i am trying to set custom claims in the jwt token that i am taking it from https://localhost:9443/oauth2/token something like username, id etc.. and later pass it to my service.
when i decode token i do not find the username but the scope exists

here is my request:

```
curl --location 'https://localhost:9443/oauth2/token' \
--header 'Authorization: Basic Y19uYVlMWTVQTF9rYndvNmsyeVZzYWc1cWcwYToyU1RUMWlrQ2VwNUc5UHZZcExXRmtlOGs3SDRh' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data '{
    "username":"asdasd",
    "grant_type":"client_credentials",
    "scope":"test1"
}'
```

i got this :

```
{
  "sub": "admin",
  "aut": "APPLICATION",
  "aud": "c_naYLY5PL_kbwo6k2yVsag5qg0a",
  "nbf": 1707997026,
  "azp": "c_naYLY5PL_kbwo6k2yVsag5qg0a",
  "scope": "default",
  "iss": "https://localhost:9443/oauth2/token",
  "exp": 1708000626,
  "iat": 1707997026,
  "jti": "39282b4d-03a6-4e1d-a7f5-2c4bf8fb46a6",
  "client_id": "c_naYLY5PL_kbwo6k2yVsag5qg0a"
}
```

but i expected this:

```
{
  "username:"asdasd",
  "sub": "admin",
  "aut": "APPLICATION",
  "aud": "c_naYLY5PL_kbwo6k2yVsag5qg0a",
  "nbf": 1707997026,
  "azp": "c_naYLY5PL_kbwo6k2yVsag5qg0a",
  "scope": "default",
  "iss": "https://localhost:9443/oauth2/token",
  "exp": 1708000626,
  "iat": 1707997026,
  "jti": "39282b4d-03a6-4e1d-a7f5-2c4bf8fb46a6",
  "client_id": "c_naYLY5PL_kbwo6k2yVsag5qg0a"
}
```

even if the result i am trying to get can't be done using this approach i want to know, and i want to know what do you think of it.